# Make Up navigation transition the same as Back or Close

Tags: android, xml, transition

I am using custom transitions in my app and I would like UP navigation to display the same transition that back navigation displays.

My transition .xml in my style is as follows:

```
<style name="YourAnimation.Activity" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity"> 
   <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item> 
   <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item> 
   <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item> 
   <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

Im looking for a simple fix preferably something like this:

```
<item name="android:parentActivityEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item> 
<item name="android:parentActivityExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By doing this, you are making the up navigation button function exactly like the back button. I think this is the wrong behavior because the up navigation should transition to the top of the Task where as the back navigation just pop the existing activity off the stack.